# Unit test for React App: useNavigate problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I'm writing a test unit for my Login component, but I'm stuck in a useNavigate problem, I couldn't find a solution for it, I'm using react 18, so I couldn't use testing-library/react-hooks or enzyme.

here is my Login.jsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  FormControl,
  Input,
  InputAdornment,
  InputLabel,
  Box,
  Alert,
} from "@mui/material";
import AccountCircle from "@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle";
import HttpsIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Https";
import logo from "../assets/logo_black_back.png";
import { ReactComponent as Svg } from "../assets/animation.svg";
import { PendingPage } from "../components";

import "./login.css";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLogin } from "../hooks/useLogin";
import { useUserContxt } from "../context/authenticationContext";

function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();
  const { login, error } = useLogin();
  const { user, isPending } = useUserContxt();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    login(email, password);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user && isPending === false) {
      navigate("/dashboard");
    }
  }, [user, isPending, navigate]);

  return !user && isPending === false ? (
    <Box
      sx={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100vh",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Box
        sx={{
          flex: 1,
          display: { xs: "none", lg: "flex" },
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Box>
          <Svg />
        </Box>
      </Box>
      <Box
        sx={{
          flex: 1,
          display: "flex",
          boxShadow: 1,
          borderRadius: "40px 0 0 40px",
          flexDirection: "column",
          p: 2,
          justifyContent: "flex-start",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Box sx={{ width: 150, height: 150, m: 10, mb: 5 }}>
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
        </Box>
        <Box
          onSubmit={submit}
          component="form"
          sx={{ width: { xs: "350px", lg: "400px" } }}
        >
          <FormControl variant="standard" sx={{ width: "100%", mb: 5 }}>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="email">EMAIL</InputLabel>
            <Input
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              id="email"
              startAdornment={
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <AccountCircle />
                </InputAdornment>
              }
            />
          </FormControl>
          <FormControl variant="standard" sx={{ width: "100%", mb: 5 }}>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="password">PASSWORD</InputLabel>
            <Input
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              id="password"
              type="password"
              startAdornment={
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <HttpsIcon />
                </InputAdornment>
              }
            />
          </FormControl>
          <Box sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained">
              LOGIN
            </Button>
            <Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
              <Button variant="text" color="error">
                BACK TO HOME
              </Button>
            </Link>
          </Box>
          {error && <Alert severity="warning">{error}</Alert>}
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  ) : (
    <PendingPage />
  );
}

export default Login;
```

and here is the test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render, screen, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useLogin } from '../hooks/useLogin';
import { useUserContxt } from '../context/authenticationContext';
import Login from './Login';

jest.mock('../hooks/useLogin');
jest.mock('../context/authenticationContext');

describe('Login', () => {
  const mockLogin = jest.fn();
  const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
  const mockedUsedNavigate = jest.fn();

  jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom"),
    useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    useLogin.mockReturnValue({
      login: mockLogin,
      error: null,
    });

    useUserContxt.mockReturnValue({
      user: null,
      isPending: false,
      dispatch: mockDispatch,
    });

    jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation(() => {});
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it('should render Login component correctly', () => {
    render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Login />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );

    expect(screen.getByText('EMAIL')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('PASSWORD')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('LOGIN')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('BACK TO HOME')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('should update email and password state when typing', async () => {
    render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Login />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );

    const emailInput = screen.getByLabelText('EMAIL');
    const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText('PASSWORD');

    fireEvent.change(emailInput, { target: { value: 'test@test.com' } });
    fireEvent.change(passwordInput, { target: { value: 'password123' } });

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(emailInput).toHaveValue('test@test.com');
      expect(passwordInput).toHaveValue('password123');
    });
  });

  it('should call login function when form is submitted', async () => {
    render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Login />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );

    const emailInput = screen.getByLabelText('EMAIL');
    const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText('PASSWORD');
    const loginButton = screen.getByText('LOGIN');

    fireEvent.change(emailInput, { target: { value: 'test@test.com' } });
    fireEvent.change(passwordInput, { target: { value: 'password123' } });
    fireEvent.click(loginButton);

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(mockLogin).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test@test.com', 'password123');
    });
  });
  it('should navigate to dashboard when user and isPending are false', async () => {
    useUserContxt.mockReturnValue({
      user: {},
      isPending: false,
      dispatch: mockDispatch,
    });

    render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Login />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(mockedUsedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/dashboard');
    });
  });
});
```

the problem is in the last test "should navigate to dashboard when user and isPending are false"

I'm expecting the "/dashboard" path to be called.

Comment: At first I thought there was an issue with the way you mocked the `useNavigate` hook, but that *seems* ok. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your UI and test code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: I haven't got time to post an answer explaining the changes that I have made, but here is a sandbox with the test passing: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/trusting-star-vnwfy2?file=%2Fsrc%2Flogin.test.tsx%3A5%2C27. I'll write an answer later

Comment: After refactoring the code I agree with Taylor Smock's answer. The code above is a slightly different approach, but otherwise solves the problem in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I fixed it by moving the mock code to the global scope at the start of the file (prior to the test code).

Specifically, for you, it would look like

```js
import Login from './Login';

jest.mock('../hooks/useLogin');
jest.mock('../context/authenticationContext');

const mockedUsedNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom"),
  useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate
}));

describe('Login', () => {
  const mockLogin = jest.fn();
  const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(() => {
    [...snip...]
```